# solving a non-linear Matrix equation

Tags: matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-equations

I am working on a problem of optimization of wireless sensor networks in order to achieve the optimal power allocation in the network. I find  an equality matrix problem  that can be written as follows:
$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {{{(Q + A - {u_i}u_i^H)}^{ - 1}}{u_i}u_i^H{{(Q + A - {u_i}u_i^H)}^{ - 1}} = QBQ}$

$A$ and $B$ are given $PSD$  symmetric matrix.
$U_i$ are also given and they verify:
$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {{u_i}u_i^H = A +aI} $ $a$ is positive integer.

I'm looking for method to find the objective matrix$ (n,n)$ $Q
\ge 0 
$  "closed form or numeric solution of th PSD matrix $ Q$".